# $\forall \epsilon>0 , \exists$ a finite linear combination of charactristic functions of intervals such that $\|f-\phi\|_{L^1}<\epsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be non-negative function in $L^1=L^1([0,1],\lambda)$. Prove that for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists a finite linear combination of charactristic functions of intervals  , $\phi = \sum c_i \chi_{[a_i,b_i)}$ , such that $\|f-\phi\|_{L^1}<\epsilon$.
[image]

My understanding of the question is that it is asking to prove that there exists a sequence of step functions that converges in $L^1$ to function $f$. Is it right?

($\textbf{Side question}$: Is the question as of showing that we can approximate any measurable function $f$ by a sequence of simple functions? If not what is the difference between this question and that?)

My attempt:

Let $E=[0,1]$ since $f\in L^1$ and $\lambda(E)<\infty$, we have that $f\leq L$ for some $L>0$. let $E=\bigcup_{i=1}^M E_i$ , $E_j\cap E_l=\phi , \forall j\neq l$ and $h=\sum a_i \chi_{E_i}$ be a sequence of simple functions that converges pointwise to $f$ such that $|f-h|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

let $A^i = \{x | \chi_{E_i}\neq \chi_{\cup[a_i,b_i)}\}$, then let the $\lambda(A^i)<\frac{\epsilon}{2Ma_i}$ . so $\|h-\phi\|_{L^1(E_i)}<\frac{\epsilon}{2M}$.

so we have 
\begin{align}
\|f-\phi\|_1 
& \leq \|f-h\|_1+\|h-\phi\|_1 = \|f-h\|_1 + \int_{\cup E_i} |f-\phi|d\lambda  \\
& = \|f-h\|_1 + \sum_{i=1}^M\int_{E_i} |f-\phi|d\lambda\\
& = \|f-h\|_1 + \sum_{i=1}^M\|h-\phi\|_{L^1(E_i)}\\
& \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + M.\frac{\epsilon}{2M}\\
& = \epsilon
\end{align}

$\textbf{Question}:$My friend was also suggesting that I could not see what is the problem with that if it is not working , the solution looked simple though. Taking an increasing sequence of simple function $\phi_n$ that converges pointwise to $f$ . That is $\phi_n \leq f $. so we'd have that using monotone convergence theorem , $\lim \int_E\phi_n =\int_E \phi \leq \int_E f$ then it follows that also $\|f-\phi\|_{L^1(E)}\to 0$

Comment: An integrable function need not be bounded.

Comment: but if the measure of the domain is also finite it is bounded right?

Comment: No. $\frac 1 {\sqrt x}$ is integrable on $(0,1)$ but it is not bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Why the sets $A_i$ have measure $<\frac{\epsilon}{2Ma_i}$?.This may not be the case.

Also $f$ is not bounded.

You know that  simple functions are dense on $L^1$ thus you exists $h=\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i1_{E_i}$

So you have to approximate each $E_i$.

Let $\epsilon>0$

We have that $\lambda(E_i)<\infty$ and that $E_i$ is measurable.

Thus exist disjoint open intervals $I_1,...I_{m_{i}}$ such that $$\lambda(E_i \cap \triangle \bigcup_{j=1}^{m_i} I_j)<\frac{\epsilon}{\sum_{i=1}^k|a_i|}$$

Thus $$\int_0^1|1_{E_i}-1_{\bigcup_{j=1}^{m_i}}| \leq \lambda(E_i \cap \triangle \bigcup_{j=1}^{m_i} I_j)<\frac{\epsilon}{\sum_{i=1}^k|a_i|}$$

Note that the intervals are disjoint so the indicator of the union is the sum of indicators.

Can you continue from here to prove the approximation of $h$ by a simple function with intervals?

Comment: It is doubtful if the approximation result you have used is permitted here.

Comment: what is this theorem? and what is $\triangle$ operator?

Comment: is the second solution I wrote working?

Comment: @stat_yale the triangle is the symmetric difference of sets...the second solution with lusin does not work since lusin's theorem involves continuous functions..here you do not need continuous functions

Comment: @MariosGretsas Lusin was a mistake. All above before the "Question" is one solution. I wanted to know about the "Question" at the end which is another proposed solution by my friend.

Comment: @stat_yale your friend prooves approximation by simple functions..not every simple function is a linear combination of indicator functions of intervals.

Comment: @MariosGretsas I thought every step function is also a simple function. so if it holds for simple functions it also holds for step functions.

Comment: @stat_yale  yes..but unfortunately this is not always the case.the class of simple functions with intervals(they are called step functions  b.t.w) is a proper subset of the class of simple functions

Comment: @KaboMurphy  i'm not using a specific approximation result,..just a property of lebesgue measurable sets of finite measure.